# What is the purpose of catalog_category_view handle in bundle.xml file?

Tags: category, layout, category-tree, layout-update

I know that magento process `catalog_category_view` handle (category action handle) before processing `catalog_category_default` or `catalog_category_layered` (category layout definition handles ).

Magento is using `category layout definition handles` for defining category layouts. Especially these handles actually defines `product_list` block. But if you look on `bundle.xml` file, you can see this code snippet

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

Since `product_list` block is not existing when magento process `catalog_category_view`, then what this code actually stands for !!!!

For me, it seems that they are doing nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that no one is answering my own question and hence I want to share my conclusion on this topic.

If you inspect `bundle.xml`, you can see these layout update codes.

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>

<catalog_product_compare_index>
    <reference name="catalog.compare.list">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_compare_index>
```

Here we can see that every layout handles holds the same content. Though the layout updates inside the layout update handle `catalog_category_view` is irrelevant, the other two layout update handles will get into action depending up on the type of category requested.

May be the core team did a wrong assignment in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It adds the renderer for Bundled Product Prices to the `product_list` block, so that when it trys to render price via `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>` in your `catalog/product/list.phtml` file you get the price rendered out properly for your product type.  In the case of Bundled Products it might say something like **Starting At** or **As Low As** depending on the theme you're using, or if you've added `bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml` to your theme to customize it.

Comment: What you have said is right. But I think you misunderstood my questoin. `product_list` block is absent when magento process the layout handle `catalog_category_view`. This is because, `product_list` block is defined by the layout handle `catalog_category_default` which will be processed by magento after processing `catalog_category_view`. So the code snippet in question seems to have no relevance, according to me..

Comment: I did misunderstand your question!  And now I want to know the answer as much as you.